# iOS - wakeup application when a/any bluetooth device is connected

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, wakeup

Is there any way to "wake-up" (relaunch) an iOS application (a background task actually, not to show the application) whenver a bluetooth device is connected?

For example, the iOS OS kills the application due to memory lack. Then a couple of hours later the user connects his bluetooth device. Can the iOS notify my application that the bluetooth device is connected and run a background task?

In Android I see that I can create a BroadcastReceiver that is registered for when a bluetooth device is connected. I need something equivalent to that for iOS.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a pending `connect` for your BLE peripheral and you have specified BLE [central background mode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW6) then yes, your app will be relaunched.  You also need to implement [state preservation and restoration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW10) as described in the Core Bluetooth programming guide in the event that your app is actually killed (not just in the background).

Note that in iOS a user cannot connect to a BLE peripheral directly - your app is responsible for identifying the target BLE peripheral and issuing the `connect` command.  This is described in the programming guide.